# Complex integration upper semi-circle $\int f(z)dz$ when $r>1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Question: Let $r$ be a real number, $r > 0$ and let $Lr$ be the line from the point $−r$ to $r$ in $C$. Let $γr$
be the upper half circle with radius $r$ and center in $0$. 
$$
\ f(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^2}\,.
$$

Compute  $\int f(z)dz$ when $r>1$

Answer:

I having trouble answering the last question about when $r>1$, I have done line integral with $Lr$ and separately for $γr$ when $r<1$ using Cauchy's Integral Formula. Now for $r>1$

$$
\ \int_{γr}^\ f(z)\,dz
$$ 
Using the Residue formula for the simple pole in the interior $z=\mathbb i$ I know for the contour integral where $γ$ is the join of $Lr$ and $γr$ that
$$
\  \int_{γ}^\ f(z)\,dz = π
$$
My problem is how to finish the answer. By splitting the last integral
$$
\  \int_{γ}^\ f(z)\,dz = \int_{Lr}^\ f(z)\,dz + \int_{γr}^\ f(z)\,dz = π + 0 = π
$$
I see that second integral on r.h.s goes to zero as $r$ grows to infinity. Is this the right way to approach? I have seen other examples and questions approaching exactly this, but where do I stop?

Comment: Since you know the integral over $L_r,$ you're done.